# Remove get method from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get-method

I want to remove get method from url using htaccess

> Bad Url:  mysite.com/index.php?sub=usr1 
>   Good Url: mysite.com/urs1

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using a CMS? Please remember that there are much more efficient ways of doing this than using a .htaccess.

Comment: You already tagged htaccess... this  + url rewrite should be your search term for google

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<Location /index.php?sub=usr1>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Location>
```

Probably some better solutions though, but I tried to avoid `mod_rewrite`.

Note that this will allow you to whitelist specific IPs if need be too.
This is a basic block, if you're looking to block ALL values for a specific parameter then that will obviously require different code, so please do clarify.

**EDIT**: After some clarification, I came up with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)$ index.php?sub=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I think this is fine but I'm not sure, will wait for some feedback. My thinking is that it'll grab the value and then replace that to the root URL (example.com/$1 where $1 is your GET parameter value).

Comment: _Something like this should work..._ Yes "something" like this should work but not "this".... Have you read OPs question carefully?

Comment: Not sure, does he want a redirect? I assumed he is looking to block the URL posted in OP?

Comment: _does he want a redirect?_ He clearly says: _I want to remove get method from url using htaccess_ and shows an example

Comment: Yeah, I think I get what you mean. I actually made this before for one of my websites but it was a while back. Tried applying it for the above code, let me know what corrections you can make to what I added to my answer please.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Hmm it's working for me. Have you tried going to www.website.com/usr1 ?